# Kotlin - get name from lambda expression

Tags: kotlin

I want to get the name of a parameter passed into a lambda expression in Kotlin. *In C# I would use an `Expression<Func<T, ...>>` to get the parameter name, but I'm not sure whether this is possible in Kotlin*

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo = Foo<Model>()
    foo.bar { it.age }
    // Should print "age"
}

data class Model(val id: UUID, val name: String, val age: Int)

class Foo<T> {
    fun bar(expression: (x: T) -> Any) {
        println(/*The name of the parameter*/)
    }
}
```

Is this possible in Kotlin?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass a property which name shall be printed? Since age does not function as a “parameter” here

Comment: @s1m0nw1 ...yes (I think?)

Comment: Try to pass a KProperty<*> directly (change parameter type) and use its name in bar. Passed as an argument like this: foo.bar(foo::age)

Comment: @s1m0nw1 not sure what you mean, would you mind providing an answer?

Comment: I did but can’t test it currently:[

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.2.21 there is no expression tree support as in C#. Also it was not on the roadmap as of November, 2017 - https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/expression-trees/158/7. So, yes, you have to fall back to use of `KProperty`.

Comment: FYI, you can always look at bytecode, find action in idea, go to show kotlin or java bytecode, and you can see that there is reference to Model, age, is actually called as getAge right in the invoke and has no reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass around properties and print their names, you can do it by using [`KProperty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo = Foo<Model>()
    foo.bar(Model::age)
}

class Foo<T> {
    fun bar(p: KProperty<*>) {
        println(p.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost works, except you can't pass `foo::age` because `age` is a property of `Model`

Comment: Model::age then? Well probably not what you want to achieve I’m afraid

Comment: Yes. It might not be exactly what I wanted, but it does the job!